# Example of Series such that $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum a_n^4$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

I am interested in finding

Example of Series such that $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum a_n^4$ diverges

I am able to find converse like if  $\sum a_n^4$ converges but $\sum a_n$ diverges using harmonic series

But I not able to find suitable example for above

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Try something alternating, e.g.
$$ a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[4]{n}}. $$

Comment: thanks again I missed this

Comment: Wow, I gave precisely the same example. I promise I didn't just copy your answer, I wrote my answer up independently...

Comment: Yes, I just have realised it, I've deleted that comment.

Answer (score 4):

When $|a_n|<1$ you have that $|a_n|^4 < |a_n|$. Therefore, the convergence of $\sum |a_n|$ guarantees the convergence of $\sum |a_n|^4$.

Hence, to answer your question you must use negative terms. One approach is to use alternating series.

For example, consider the series of the sequence

$$a_n = (-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{n}} $$

such that $a_n^4 = 1/n$ gives rise to the Harmonic series.

The convergence of $\sum a_n$ can be established (without finding the exact sum) using the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), whereas $\sum a_n^4$ is the Harmonic series [which diverges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence).